# Show that mapping is a contraction?

Tags: metric-spaces, fixed-point-theorems

Show that the mapping $f:\Bbb R \to \Bbb R $, $f(x)=1-xe^x$ is a contraction. I tried everything i could think of but i cant get it to work. Witch is not much since i couldn't really find any inequality that would be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: It's not a contraction for all $x\in\mathbb{R}$ - $\vert f(1)-f(0)\vert=e>1$. Perhaps you mean for $x\leq0$?

Comment: well, the original problem was, show that the equation $x+xe^x-1=0$ has a unique fixpoint in $\Bbb R$ using Banach's Fix point theorem i.e. if $f:X \to X$ and $X$ is complete and $f$ is a contraction then there is a unique fix-point in $X$.

Comment: Yep, that is how the theorem works. The equation you've given does lead to $x=1-x e^x$, but this is unlikely to work here - if the solution is $x_*$, then you can actually show that $f'(x_*)=-1-e^{x_*}<-1$, which means that $x_*$ is a repelling fixed point of $f$. You'll want to seek a different iteration.

Comment: I don't know, that was on the exam today but what you noticed is absolutely correct, maybe its a mistake in the problem formulation. is there any other way to proof the existence of a fix-point?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[solution to: Show that the equation $x+xe^x-1=0$ has a unique solution in $\mathbb{R}$ using Banach's fixed point theorem]

Rearranging these equations for iterative approximations of the form $x_{n+1}=f(x_n)$, we generally want to aim for $f$ which decay or grow slowly, so as to make them contractive. Given that the largest term in our equation is an $e^x$, we'd like to divide by this if possible. According to this heuristic, we might rearrange our equation as:

$x(1+e^x)=1\implies x= \frac{1}{1+e^x}$

So, we could choose to iterate using $f(x)=\frac{1}{1+e^x}$, suspecting that it might be contractive. We differentiate using the chain rule:

$f'(x)=\frac{-e^x}{(1+e^x)^2}\implies\vert f'(x)\vert=\frac{e^x}{e^{2x}+2e^x+1}=\frac{1}{e^x+2+e^{-x}}\leq1/2$

(with a little extra work, we can tighten this to $\vert f'(x)\vert\leq 1/4$)

In any case, the bound on the derivative gives us a Lipschitz condition on $f$, as the mean value theorem tells us:

$$\vert \frac{f(x) - f(y)}{x-y}\vert=\vert f'(\xi)\vert\leq1/2\implies\vert f(x)-f(y)\vert\leq(1/2)\vert x-y\vert$$

Thus, $f$ is contractive on $\mathbb{R}$,  which is complete. We can then apply the Banach fixed point theorem to deduce that $f$ has a unique fixed point in $\mathbb{R}$, and thus that the equation $x+xe^x-1=0$ has a unique solution in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: Great, Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

A function is a contraction if the points in the image are closer together than in the source. In symbols: $|\mathrm f(y) - \mathrm f(x)| < |y-x|$.

Let's choose $y$ to be a tiny bit bigger than $x$, i.e. $y=x+\varepsilon$. The definition becomes
$$|\mathrm{f}(x+\varepsilon)-\mathrm{f}(x)| < |(x+\varepsilon)-x|$$
$$|\mathrm{f}(x+\varepsilon)-\mathrm{f}(x)| < |\varepsilon|$$
Since $\varepsilon \neq 0$, we can divide by $|\varepsilon|$ to give
$$\frac{|\mathrm{f}(x+\varepsilon)-\mathrm{f}(x)|}{|\varepsilon|} < 1$$
$$\left|\frac{\mathrm{f}(x+\varepsilon)-\mathrm{f}(x)}{\varepsilon}\right| < 1$$
If we let $y$ get closer and closer to $x$ we have $\varepsilon \to 0$, and so
$$\lim_{\varepsilon \to 0}\left|\frac{\mathrm{f}(x+\varepsilon)-\mathrm{f}(x)}{\varepsilon}\right| < 1$$
The thing on the right looks just like the definition of a derivative. In fact, it becomes
$$\color{red}{|\mathrm{f}'(x)| < 1}$$
All you need to do is check that the absolute value of the derivative is less than 1 for the set of $x$-values you are given.

EDIT

The OP's definition of a contraction seems to be that, there exists $0 \le q < 1$, for which $\mathrm d(\mathrm f(x),\mathrm f(y)) \le q \cdot \mathrm d(x,y)$.
With the standard Euclidean metric $\mathrm d(x,y) = |x-y|$. If we follow the same argument through, we get: There needs to be a $0 \le q < 1$ for which $\color{red}{|\mathrm f'(x)| < q}$.

Of course, if $|\mathrm{f}'(x)| < 1$ then there exists a $0 \le q < 1$ such that $|\mathrm f'(x)| < q$. In this case $q=1$.

Comment: A function is a contraction if there exists a $0 \le q<1$ such that for all $x,y$   $d(f(x),f(y)) \le d(x,y)$?

Comment: You mentioned $q$, but then didn't use it. Where does $q$ come in to your definition?

Comment: Ah, sorry it comes on the right side of the inequality just before $d(x,y)$

Comment: @adoion It's the same definition (with the real numbers and the euclidean metric). I've added an edit to the end of the question to explain. Your definition is more general and works for any metric space. But in your example, our definitions are equivalent.

Comment: Your last line is not necessarily true on all domains - if $f(x)=\sqrt{x^2+1}$, then $\vert f'(x)\vert<1$ but gets arbitrarily close to 1, which precludes there being such a $q$. However, if you're on a closed, bounded domain, I think this can be done.